# How to pass variable in exec statment in python

Tags: python

I am having two python files as 1.py and 2.py.

```
**1.py is as** 
class A:
       def __init__(self):
              x = 5
              y = 7
              NUMBERS = self
              fp = open(filePath)
              temp = fp.read()
              exec(temp)
              fp.close()
              ADD_METHOD()

**2.py is as**
    def ADD_METHOD():
          print NUMBERS.x + NUMBERS.y
```

Now My question how this NUMBERS varaible is available in 2.py file.
This is example for better view of problem, i know i can do this by importing module but the problem is that i have to do solution with exec() method and ho can i get NUMBERS in 2.py file ie should i have to pass this with exec as argument or some other approach.

Any Help really appreciable
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the `exec` *statement*, or about `os.exec()`?

Comment: i hope this "exec(2.py)" should be statement

Comment: `exec` doesn't take filenames, so that doesn't help.

Comment: fp = open(2.py)
        temp = fp.read()
        fp.close()
        exec(temp)

can we do now this

Answer (score 2):

If these are both Python files that you wrote yourself, why not just create a function in `2.py` that you can import and call in `1.py`? This is a much easier and cleaner abstraction. It also avoids the creation of a new process. You could write something like this:

```
# **1.py is as**
from 2 import ADD_METHOD
class A:
       def __init__(self):
              x = 5
              y = 7
              ADD_METHOD(x, y)

# **2.py is as**
    def ADD_METHOD(x, y):
          print x + y
```

Note that you really should pick better names than `1.py` and `2.py` to avoid confusion later ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you need, but I have a solution to your trivial example that follows your limitations.

```
# 1.py
...
os.execl( "2.py", str( NUMBERS.x ), str( NUMBERS.y ) )

# 2.py
from collections import namedtuple
A = namedtuple( "A", "x y" )
NUMBERS = A( x=sys.argv[1], y=sys.argv[2] )
...
```